# How to handle incoming messages using Pjsip library iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, pjsip

I am using pjsip library for sending and receiving instant messages. I am able to successfully send messages using pjsip. But I don't know where and how to handle incoming messages?

Please help if anyone has already done this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: No @NandhaKumar

Comment: I think instant message is only for sending purpose...